# Is there an equalent for base_local_planner::FootprintHelper().getLineCells in nav2?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to trace a line between 2 points and I'm looking for a functionality similar to base_local_planner::FootprintHelper().getLineCells in ROS-2, any leads will be helpful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376042/is-there-an-equalent-for-base_local_planner::footprinthelper().getlinecells-in-nav2?/) by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 224 on 2021-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the line iterator https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_util/include/nav2_util/line_iterator.hpp

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1